# Update Table with random value in one column for all rows

Tags: sql, random

I am trying to update all rows for a specific column in a table with a random number between 1-3 inclusive. I've tried using this code:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET RandColumn = FLOOR(RAND() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1
```

The problem with this is that the random number is generated once and used in each row.

How do I change this so that it creates the random number for every row?

Comment: Which DBMS? They all do things differently. Is this MS SQL Server? If so, which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including example DDL and DML will make this, and questions like it,  much easier to solve. Consider:
`DECLARE @Table TABLE (Column1 INT, Column2 DATE, ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Column1, Column2, ...) VALUES (1, '2024-01-01', ...),  (2, '2024-02-01', ...);`

In addition please tag the appropriate SQL product. The answer may be different for various dialects (SQL Server, Oracle, PostGreSQL, etc).

Assuming you're using SQL Server, consider the following:

```
/* Create some demo data */
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, RandomValue INT);
INSERT INTO @Table (ID)
SELECT object_id
  FROM sys.tables;

/* Update the table using a random value between 1 and 3 for each row */
UPDATE c
   SET RandomValue = a.a
  FROM @Table c
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CAST(ROUND(((3 - 1) * RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1))) + 1,0) AS INT))) a(a);

/* review the result */
SELECT a.ID, a.RandomValue
  FROM @Table a;
```

| ID | RandomValue |
| --- | --- |
| 901578250 | 2 |
| 933578364 | 2 |
| 981578535 | 1 |
| 1006626629 | 1 |
| 1022626686 | 3 |
| 1029578706 | 3 |
| 1038626743 | 3 |
| 1054626800 | 2 |
| 1077578877 | 2 |
| 1125579048 | 3 |
| 1189579276 | 2 |
| 1253579504 | 2 |
| 1285579618 | 2 |
| 1333579789 | 2 |
| 1365579903 | 2 |
| 1445580188 | 2 |
| 1525580473 | 2 |
| 1557580587 | 2 |
| 1726629194 | 1 |
| 1742629251 | 2 |
| 1758629308 | 2 |
| 1790629422 | 2 |

This works by creating a random value per row using `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: The APPLY is unnecessary, the "per row" behaviour is caused by NEWID()

Comment: `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` is faster I believe, and will have similar entropy.